# Find the percentage

Tags: code-golf, math, array, arithmetic

<sub><sub>We haven't had any nice, easy challenges in a while, so here we go.</sub></sub>

Given a list of integers each greater than \$0\$ and an index as input, output the percentage of the item at the given index of the total sum of the list.

Output should be whatever the natural representation for floats/integers is in your language (unary, decimal, Church numerals etc.). If you choose to round the output in any way, it must have at minimum 2 decimal places (when reasonable. \$1.2\$ doesn't *need* to be rounded, but \$1.20\$ is also perfectly acceptable).

Indexes can be either 1-indexed or 0-indexed, and will always be within the bounds of the array.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins!

### Examples

Using 1-indexed and rounded to 2 d.p

```
list, index                    =>         output
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 5             => 5 / 15    => 33.33
[7, 3, 19], 1                  => 7 / 29    => 24.14
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 6 => 1 / 9     => 11.11
[20, 176, 194, 2017, 3], 1     => 20 / 2410 => 0.83
[712], 1                       => 712 / 712 => 100
```

Or, as three lists:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [7, 3, 19], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [20, 176, 194, 2017, 3], [712]]
[5, 1, 6, 1, 1]
[33.33, 24.14, 11.11, 0.83, 100]
```

Comment: [Sandbox post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12947/66833) (now deleted)

Comment: how exactly can non-integers be output as unary / church numerals?

Comment: @Doorknob Maybe a unary number, the dot, and another unary number?

Comment: Since the output can be rounded to two decimal places, it might also be permissible to output rounded times 100?

Comment: What if I don't choose to round the result, given that I only have an integer division operator?

Comment: test case 4 should be 20/2410

Comment: @Doorknob I don't know, I was just allowing people to take input in the most natural way

Comment: @Neil Only using integer division isn't acceptable, sorry

Comment: "Given a list of integers", it says. Can I take `[1.0]` in place of `[1]`?

Comment: @Khuldraesethna'Barya Yes that's perfectly fine

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 26 bytes

```python
lambda i,a:a[i]/sum(a)*100
```

An unnamed function accepting an integer (0-indexed index) and a list which returns the percentage.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSFTJ9EqMTozVr@4NFcjUVPL0MDgf0FRZl6JRpqGiU60oY6RjrGOiY5prKbmfwA)**

Answer (score 6):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 9 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

Anonymous tacit infix function. Takes index as left argument and list as right argument.

```apl
100×⌷÷1⊥⊢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///39DA4PD0Rz3bD283fNS19FHXov9pj9omPOrte9Q31dP/UVfzofXGj9omAnnBQc5AMsTDM/g/kPYK9vfTgNLq0aY6CoY6CmZg0jBWXTPt0Aq4XDRQzEhHwVhHwURHwTRWRyHaHMwztASxDSF6MBFI0sgAyDAHGWsJ1GtkYAjSCTbB0Cg2Vh0A)

`100` one hundred

`×` times

`⌷` the indexed element

`÷` divided by

`1⊥` the sum (lit. the base-1 evaluation) of

`⊢` the right argument

Answer (score 6):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 22 bytes

```cs
x=>y=>x[y]*100/x.Sum()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZBLT4NAFIXX5VeMrAY7xRnoQ62QuFA3mhpdmFhZUDqkUyttYFAI4bfjHV6pj4RkuPd@59wzEySjIBHVbRoFV@t9utrxpUfqSkSSNB3XDZ0qc9zccbNl7p0ySs8y8zn9wEY11z79GInokEqGHBTxL9TZLL3iuCwYQRZBNkFjgiYl@cEWs3rCLn73QfT/9xu0KDRnU@UB/hZlyvHPFmaV5VFkq4kMk0ntOm29GyTmSbqTPWLbpg0ZrbHJYANjJgOWmucqN6WggRdDAnBIslXHXAv3MfeDDVZu2CcrA9a2j2W@igNuQhCckdxw3PowDFRog8cYzLBvzLvf1Yipoo0F7g@@3JhP@zRa4xDAGiBWx/DswAPJ1wA2t1iK4dCDoQgRVgYnTs/UCwcvsZAc6zedsKDweHd7iQpW6qSHifJTWwbb4RCOUhvwXcJRK1@kEm50qdR6j9azexHB/C3SoVNqKsYWuYganRIUSPJEBn4C8UJf7PgaLLaAHy@4Hi3e/RxMqm8)

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ị÷S}ȷ2×
```

A dyadic Link accepting an integer, one-based index on the left and a list of numbers on the right which yields the percentage.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///h7u7D24NrT2w3Ojz9////pv@jDXUUjHQUjHUUTHQUTGMB)**

#### How?

```
ị÷S}ȷ2× - Link: integer, i; list, L
ị       - (i) index into (L)
   }    - use right argument:
  S     -   sum (L)
 ÷      - divide
    ȷ2  - literal 10^2 = 100
      × - multiply
```

Comment: Nice! That's byte for byte what I had :P

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
è²O/т*
```

A full program taking the index then the list. Uses 0-indexing.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8IpDm/z1LzZp/f9vwhVtqGOkY6xjomMaCwA)**

#### How?

```
è²O/т*
è      - index (input 1) into (input 2)
 ²     - push 2nd input
  O    - sum
   /   - divide
    т  - push 100
     * - multiply
       - print top of stack
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 47 bytes

```java
a->i->1e2*a[i]/java.util.Arrays.stream(a).sum()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZFRa4MwFIXf@ysuBUFL6tS1K2tXoTAGe9jT9iY@ZDWWdGokuZYV8bd3SXTt6IoGyfluzvXc7OmBTvfZ14mXtZAIe733G@SFP1mN/ml5U22Ri8rAbUGVgjfKK2hHAHXzWfAtKKSoPwfBMyg1c99R8mqXpEDlTnm2FOBl8HniFSYp@RDPQh9nZ/m1QrZjMo4hh/WJTmM@jUMWTWjC07vL72ykpEflK5SMli71fNWUrnda2R7W2jyATKGC9dAboIU2JBARuCcwIzDviNFm0EFHLiULy8NHTVsIrqA@f/u11fOr6ijQZPFg3HS/KAiN903fRRgZPTirXR8mFxLcIZHNs@xTeedQFuoh64noqAYmQbq6QL0y9v2LwvQPfT8qZKUvGvRrfVmYu2NHEXCyJTjKqcYEhkGj6G/TtW080nsSyH1a18VxkPvNRvV36toaz@ubdSOzutMP)

Comment: Why did you wrote `1e2` instead of `100`? Is it because `100` is integer and `1e2` is considered as a floating point number?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Yes: `1e2` carries the double type, which `a[i]` and the sum don't. Since the challenge requires to return floating point numbers, that's where I can use it.

Comment: Change it to a BiFunction<int[], Integer, Double> and you can save 10 bytes with this: `(a,i)->1e2*a[i]/IntStream.of(a).sum()`. Edit: >:( my poor lambda arrow

Comment: @Avi The import is still required, so I'd have to write: `(a,i)->1e2*a[i]/java.util.stream.IntStream.of(a).sum()`, which is 54 bytes long. My current answer is only 47 bytes long. Also, `a->i->` is one byte shorter than `(a,i)->`.

Comment: Is the import required? That's weird, I thought it wouldn't be

Comment: @Avi [Yes, they are required](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/383/should-imports-includes-count-in-golf), and it's usually shorter to write the full class name instead of the import, so that's what I do here

Comment: Do things in the JDK count as built-ins or external libraries? Edit: nevermind, I think I understand now.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Thank you. That makes sense.

Answer (score 4):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 10 bytes

```
100*{%1#.]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/DQ0MtKpVDZX1Yv9rcilwpSZn5CuYKKQpGCoYKRgDWaYQIQOgkDlQwNASwjcFK0GDCKVGBgqG5mZA1SZApiFQI5Iphkb/AQ)

0-indexed

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/) 28 bytes

```
function(n,l)100*l[n]/sum(l)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfVpqnYKMLopJLMvPzNPJ0cjQNDQy0cqLzYvWLS3M1cjT/5wBVKBhamXKBlCqYcgEVA9UpAGW4AA)

Comment: I don't know R, but this doesn't look like it works (not sure how to test it on TIO with arbitrary arrays), as you are supposed to retrieve the element of `l` at index `n`, not just divide by `n` (see the `[7, 3, 19], 1` testcase)

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing My bad, had a typo (forgot the `l[]` around the `n`)

Comment: There's a thing on the TIO link page that can format this for you.

Answer (score 4):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 64 bytes

0-indexed. The only fun bit was the realization that `1e2` is a `double`, saving a byte over `100.`!

```c
float f(v,n,t)int*v;{n=v[n];for(t=0;*v;t+=*v++);return n*1e2/t;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZDRboMgFIbvfYoTF1sEumm3rNkY3YM0vaAoLYnFRtGLNT47A6wXvYAc/gPf/x/k5iylc6pphQWFRmqozbWxeGR3w8eDOTLVdsjygnnJEo5HQnLW1XboDBhc1ts3yyb3oo1shqqGn95Wun297JMnqdGnoCUeDVehDQqF6M6SgryIDjD2hzGHewIQWngUTU8BawpmuLIkyD6eF7kUTdNKND/u9V/dqkDL8/k1QAis@Qy4DTbw0fqwzlk03GxgtQKENRe21QgTEp1999Z5jEJp1mdVGrwJ4TwG@U3Tb69E0d@MLj5OwC2mEHI@I9mjsXCPFLIK@B4ylcaxKMwjxcPCnZKw/Pb444Ilk3PbwpW7T1d@ffiy3Ll3V7jiHw)

Comment: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY7LCoMwFAX3@YrQUkg01WiLD27tj4gLq6YNpNeiMRvx261CN12eYRhOc25Mjc91RWFBmb62VDHP8RkLV2IFqh@YLSR4DqxfeM73OQydnQak6EVdHFpY1qPGxkxtR2@jbXUfvO7kDxn92BnRaOm71sg4nQml@3S1GcuqmGMpojQRUX4VsYxScRFyAfIZNkdRdjipg1BslzkHEoYyyOI8SxOyZX53JJBl/QI "C (clang) – Try It Online") 59 using C(clang)

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 30 bytes

Takes input as `(array)(index)`, where *index* is 0-based.

```javascript
a=>n=>a[n]*100/eval(a.join`+`)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dc/fCoIwFMfxe5/iXGrZPGebmRf6IiI4zEKRLTJ8fdvsD6U1ZLALP3x/nRrVUF/by22nzbGZTtmkslxnuSp0uSHEqBlV7yvWmVZX2yqYaqMH0zesN2f/5BcUAg9BhCBDiMvAl0EAXyeKIIYIKHaPLAchmBDeQklmglIL4BJ4KYlVePpUuGQkvXXL78@ysWOtQlaZEacQMaKlwtH@kexdjt3EkVzcZ5hVOLoYSegUZIf1IOJ/t7wHEYfH7VIQpzs)

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/),  <s>20</s>  18 bytes

```hs
i?a=a!!i/sum a*100
```

A dyadic operator (`?`) taking the (0-indexed) index on the left and a list on the right which yields the percentage.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P9M@0TZRUTFTv7g0VyFRy9DA4H9uYmaegq1CSj6XgoJCQVFmXomCioKJgr1CtKGOgpGOgrGOgomOgmnsfwA)**

Answer (score 3):

## [PHP](https://php.net/) (7.4), 35 bytes

```php
fn($l,$i)=>100/array_sum($l)*$l[$i]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRwMWlkmb7Py1PQyVHRyVT09bO0MBAP7GoKLEyvrg0FyiqqaWSE62SGfvfmosrNTkjX0ElTSPaUEfBSEfBWEfBREfBNBZIaVpz/QcA)

Input index is 0-based.

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 15 bytes

```
100##[[]]/Tr@#&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b739DAQFk5Ojo2Vj@kyEFZ7X9AUWZeSbSyrl2ag4NyrJq@QzVXdbWhjpGOsY6JjmktCAEFzIFcQ8taHUMwz1AHDcIkjAx0DM3NgCpNdIwMDIGaYBLmhkYgJlftfwA)

Input as `list, index`

Comment: `##[[]]` is awesome!

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 9 bytes

```
)1Gs/100*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/X9PQvVjf0MBA6///aEMdIx0zIx1jnVguYwA)

#### Explanation

```
          implicitly take two inputs
)         get the entry within the first input at the index specified by the second
 1G       push the first input onto the stack again
   s      compute the sum 
    /     divide first entry of the stack by this number (the sum) 
     100* multiply by 100
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/X9PQvVj///9oQx0jHTMjHWOdWC5jAA)

Answer (score 3):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), <s>15</s> 14 bytes

-1 byte thanks to ngn!

```
{100*x[y]%+/x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/P82q2tDAQKsiujJWVVu/ovZ/mkK0kYGCobmZgqGliYKRgaG5grG1gkHsfwA)

0-indexed

Comment: `(x@y)` -> `x[y]`

Answer (score 2):

## [TI-Basic](http://en.wikipedia.org/TI-Basic), [12 bytes (12 tokens)](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1541/how-to-score-ti-basic)

```
Prompt X
Ans(X)E2/sum(Ans
```

1-indexed

Takes the list in [`Ans`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8580/44694) and prompts the user for the index

[Example run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZP69c.jpg)

Explanation:

```
Prompt X         # Prompt the user for the index
Ans(X)E2/sum(Ans
Ans(X)           # The value at the Xth index in the list
      E2         # times 100
        /sum(Ans # Divided by the sum of the list
                 # The result of the last expression in a program is implicitly returned
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), <s>31</s> 29 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to ErikF

```
func[b i][1e2 * b/:i / sum b]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XcsxDsIwEETR3qf4NU2ySxKLHIPW2sbEllwQoUDO77hCAU01o3lbWuo9LcFcnql5Xx8hUixIUi7Ebi50vPcn0eprK@uHTBCUKwOjMYL77r6tcjPEna5/MaaT0B7xU0MD2kvzP9iLtl4P)

Comment: (-2 bytes) suggest using `1e2` instead of `100.0`: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XcsxDsIwEETR3qf4NU2ySxKLHIPW2sbEllwQoUDO77hCAU01o3lbWuo9LcFcnql5Xx8hUixIUi7Ebi50vPcn0eprK@uHTBCUKwOjMYL77r6tcjPEna5/MaaT0B7xU0MD2kvzP9iLtl4P "Red – Try It Online"). It's pretty neat how many languages can use this trick!

Comment: @ErikF Thank you! I know this in theory, but as it seems, I forgot to use it :)

Answer (score 2):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), <s>32</s> 30 bytes

***-1** thanks to @ErikF, using `1e2` instead of `100.`.*

```sh
<<<$[1e2*$@[`<&0`]/(${@/#/+})]
```

<s>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@J@moVn938bGRiXa0MBAT0vFITrBRs0gIVZfQ6XaQV9ZX7tWM/Z/LVeagqGCkYKxgomCqQJQtYIpUMQcyDe0VAACkIjhfwA)</s>
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@J@moVn938bGRiXaMNVIS8UhOsFGzSAhVl9DpdpBX1lfu1Yz9n8tV5qCoYKRgrGCiYKpAlCxgilQxBzIN7RUAAKQiOF/AA)

Accepts the list as arguments and the index on stdin.

```sh
<<<$[1e2*$@[`<&0`]/(${@/#/+})]  # $[ arithmetic ]
   $[       `<&0`            ]  # capture stdin
   $[    $@[     ]           ]  # index into the arguments
   $[1e2*$@[`<&0`]           ]  # multiply by 100.0 (casts to float)
   $[              (${@/#/+})]  # prepend each element with + and add
   $[             /          ]  # divide
<<<                              # print to stdout
```

[Alternate **30 byte** solution](https://tio.run/##qyrO@J@moVn9v9hWQ1slzkGTy8bGRiXaMNVIS8UhOsFGzSAhVr849n8tV5qCoYKRgrGCiYKpAlCNgilQxBzIN7RUAAKQiOF/AA)

Comment: (-1 bytes) `1e2` instead of `100.` works just like in C to cast to float: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@J@moVn938bGRiXaMNVIS8UhOsFGzSAhVl9DpdpBX1lfu1Yz9n8tV5qCoYKRgrGCiYKpAlCxgilQxBzIN7RUAAKQiOF/AA "Zsh – Try It Online")

Comment: Oops, this beats my [39 bytes solution!](https://tio.run/##hUxNC4JAEL3vrxjcDTRhdTZdKYQkin5BJ/EUmoUfh4wg8bdv49IhusSbgfdm3nuve20q1xtNmqYix1ItRZbT8KIIXDGK0b1JX3rZFCz87eQVhksp94fd6biBR3fu27bsBhjqEqq@afrntbuQgXGqc/62OWxijFWAoGAFEcQQk0qI4xrQPn6h6apCwESTJyKK1j7HUH0y4RfQ7lw/pyPQIWlt3g)

Answer (score 2):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), <s>7</s> 6 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
§\Σ/♀*
```

0-based indexing.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///Q8phzi/UfzWzQ@v8/2lDPQMcIiI2B2ASITfUMYnVMuKLNoWKGliABAy6wQgI4VseUK9rIAMQxNwPrBZloZGAINQxsjrmhEZgFAA)

**Explanation:**

```python
§       # Index the (implicit) second input-integer into the first (implicit) input-list
 \      # Swap so the first (implicit) input-list is at the top of the stack
  Σ     # Take the sum of that input-list
   /    # Divide the earlier indexed number by this sum
    ♀*  # Multiply it by 100
        # (after which the entire stack joined together is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 46 bytes

```
: f ( i l -- n ) dup [ nth ] dip sum / 1e2 * ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYwxDoJAFAV7TjGlmqAsgkQ4gKGhMVbGgsCiRFgQlsIYz46rFBrzm/cmb36RZrrpxsM@TnYhV9kpWVGn@kIvb4NUmexpO6n1ve1KpYmsOAnJmlyem6oYQwpmlFTYNoo5@dByRBn/RF629EPNCiFdFkSjxwOByxoPn6eRl5ZjWGCI2E4Ay/@s/u@7dh1EsDGCZ6J4uz@fhDu18QU)

0-indexed

Comment: Save three bytes by replacing `dup [ nth ] dip` with `[ nth ] keep` [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYyxDoJAEER7vmJKNUG5EyQeH2BoaIyVsSC4IBEOPI7CGL/9XKXQmG1mX@ZNmRe2M@6wT7OdwpWMpgZtbi8Y6DaSLmhAb8jae29qbZF4aaZQdGequqZ0CiVmqNHA96ExxxGa3RMvUY9hbLGCIIkFEhfiAQGJNUJEeLK59AJmMROxnQC86NP6v29bBhDxhoWQo3i7P0tCTp97AQ)

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 34 bytes

```powershell
param($l,$n)$l|%{$i+=$_};$l[$n]/$i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY7dCoJAEEbvfYoBp3Bp0Z3dNZOwF4kIL5SEzcQuujCf3XbzhwKX2YsP5sz5mseraJ@3wpgBy6wbmrzN7wEajjVD8950WO0yvPZHNGesLxFWQ@95WywhIA6Sg@KgOcQMNPjw87ITxBABxVNQKlRqBJMvRSkD8c/MYGJBmU5B6pD0YlwfZl2@3SULpvMVopBoBKWwS8neSW1ZKchVWPROIpxSk3BBhIe5KUkGqy3npiQj@yfh8AE)

Shame parameters are so dang expensive in Powershell.

Answer (score 2):

## [Go](https://golang.org/), 79 bytes

```go
func f(a[]float64,i int)float64{s:=0.
for _,v:=range a{s+=v}
return a[i]/s*100}
```

This has a nice amount of accuracy. It takes a Go slice and uses `range` to calculate the sum.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY5NCoMwFIT3OcXDlWmDjbYoteQO3YuUhxgJ1URidBNydpv@0FkMDAzfzGD2GbsnDj1MqDQhapqNdZDIySW7XHUHMsWmlaNBV16YAqUd/SW/1IJnRBoLD7bVwqKOHPTLUWyB2N6tVgM2qj0th5zz8OW9d1IKnkAUQi3gj/cFZ5BXZbTrhUHB84rBOXya8VB2t3F91Gm8xIBTeiNhfwE)

Answer (score 2):

## Scratch 3.0 <s>24</s> 23 blocks/<s>239</s> 228 bytes

[image: -11 bytes thanks to @JoKing]

*Alternatively in SB syntax*

```
when gf clicked
set[s v]to(0
ask()and wait
repeat until<(answer)=(
add(answer)to[m v
ask()and wait
end
set[n v]to(item(length of(n))of(m
repeat(length of((m)-(1
change[s v]by(item(1)of[m v
delete (1)of[m v
end
say(((n)/(s))*(100
```

*Saved 11 bytes thanks to @JoKing*

[Try it on scratch](https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/333497999/)

### Answer History

[image: Oh Scratchblocks, why so long?]

*Alternatively in SB syntax*

```
when gf clicked
set[s v]to(0
ask()and wait
repeat until<(answer)=(
add(answer)to[m v
ask()and wait
end
set[n v]to(item(length of(n))of(m
delete(n)of[m v
repeat(length of(m
change[s v]by(item(1)of[m v
delete (1)of[m v
end
say(((n)/(s))*(100
```

[Try it on scratch](https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/333497999/)

Input is in the form of:

```
item1
item2
...
itemN
index
```

I really should stop doing this to myself. But it *is* very fun!

Comment: Can you change `repeat length of m` to `length of m-1` and save yourself the `delete n`?

Comment: No, because if I did, it wouldn't tally the last item.

Comment: Well, if you remove the `delete n of m` like I suggested then it would

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 13 bytes

```
c*100@hQeQshQ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/P1nL0MDAISMwNbA4I/D//2hDHQUjHQVjHQUTHQXTWCALAA)

First time using Pyth so theres probably some pretty big optimizations here, but I dont know where they are...

0-index, takes input as `list, index`

Answer (score 2):

## [Snap!](https://snap.berkeley.edu), 79 bytes (scratchblocks syntax)

```
((L)(i))::hat
report((combine(L)using((()+()@addInput)@addInput::grey ring))/(i
```

This is a "custom block" (function), and it takes a "list" (array) as the first argument and the idnex as the second argument.

Wow, having to manually mark hats/grey rings/grey ring inputs really makes short Snap! code in scratchblocks look relatively ugly.

Answer (score 2):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), <s>14</s> 12 bytes

*-2 bytes thanks to @luis-mendo*

```
_@=\:+d/1e2*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP1voBBtrmCsYGgZ@z/ewTbGSjtF3zDVSOv/fwA)

0-indexed. Takes input as `index [list]`

## Explanation

```
code         | explanation
-------------|------------
_@=\:+d/1e2* | whole program
 @=          | get the item at the index
_  \:+       | sum the array
      d      | convert to a *d*ouble
       /     | divide
        1e2* | multiply by 100
```

Comment: You can replace `{+}*` by `:+` ([quick fold](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam/wiki/Basic%20operators/#colon)) to save 2 bytes

Answer (score 2):

## Erlang 41 bytes

```
f(X,N)->lists:nth(N,X)/lists:sum(X)*100.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-ap -MList::Util=Sum`, 19 bytes

```perl
$_=100*$F[<>]/sum@F
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3tbQwEBLxS3axi5Wv7g018Ht/39DBSMFYy7Df/kFJZn5ecX/dRML/uv6@mQWl1hZhZZk5tgC1QEA)

Take the list, space separated on the first line, the index (0-based) on the second.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 8 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
gV
*L/Vx
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=Z1YKKkwvVng&input=NApbMSwgMiwgMywgNCwgNV0)

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 102 bytes

```
\d+
$*
^(1)+((?<-1>.(1+))+)
$3$2
,

\G1
10000$*
;(1+)\1
$1;$1$1
r`.*(\2)*;(1+)
$#1
+`^..?$
0$&
..$
.$&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYs9DsIwFIN3X4NHlTSPKE7/hILo2EtEqEgwsDBU3D@kjNiL5c/enp/X@16OZllLfjhIi5uhdcbMlxOv3tBZ6yykkwgF8kIwVNVh2mEmhEkoxLb61uRo2x@AHAi33ryfBUEaeC/w0pQyJGrUTnsdwDTVxDPGWv65whiU01h5rzGwTvcD4xc) Link includes test cases. Takes input as `index;list,...`. Explanation:

```
\d+
$*
```

Convert to unary.

```
^(1)+((?<-1>.(1+))+)
$3$2
```

Index into the list.

```
,
```

Sum the list.

```
\G1
10000$*
;(1+)\1
$1;$1$1
r`.*(\2)*;(1+)
$#1
```

Multiply the desired value by 10000 and divide by the sum with rounding by adding on half of the sum first.

```
+`^..?$
0$&
```

Ensure that the result has at least three digits.

```
..$
.$&
```

Insert a decimal point at the second last position.

Answer (score 1):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), <s><sup>77</sup></s> <s><sup>75</sup></s> <s><sup>73</sup></s> <s><sup>72</sup></s> <s><sup>80</sup></s> <s><sup>76</sup></s> 75 bytes

```bash
a=($@)
((b=10000*${a[$1]}/(${@/%/+}-$1),b<10))
echo $[b/100].${?/1}$[b%100]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY29CsJAEIT7e4opNrDr32UTExEM5j1CijsxpLOwPO7ZL6t2zjTzwQcTw3stCwuXMDCN4pjjoLVlRylMpHP2TGn0ld/nI6kc4k1rEfd8rC/QFL3J84nS3Ws2rD5YxLkFHRQNWpzRGSkutvVqszf461ew2u/P1QZA2QA)

*+8 bytes thanks to GammaFunction, who found a bug with large numbers*

*-5 bytes thanks to GammaFunction, who golfed his original bug fix*

Comment: Ah, nice catch.  Ty!

Comment: [Whoops, saved one more.](https://tio.run/##XY29CsJAEIT7e4opNrDr32UTExEM5j1CijsxpLOwPO7ZL6t2zjTzwQcTw3stCwuXMDCN4pjjoLVlRylMpHP2TGn0ld/nI6kc4k1rEfd8rC/QFL3J84nS3Ws2rD5YxLkFHRQNWpzRGSkutvVqszf461ew2u/P1QZA2QA "Bash – Try It Online") I don't think bash is going to let me be any more clever than this, though

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s><sup>25</sup></s> <s><sup>23</sup></s> 21 bytes

```ruby
->a,i{1e2*a[i]/a.sum}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y5RJ7PaMNVIKzE6M1Y/Ua@4NLf2PxdXQWlJsUKanka0oY6CkY6CsY6CiY6CaSyQ0kTImYMlDC2BwgaaKFqwI6A6UyR1RgZAMXMzkAlAw40MDEHmoZllbmgEFvkPAA)

Answer (score 1):

## AWK, <s><sup>43</sup></s> 40 bytes

```bash
{s+=a[NR]=$1}END{print 100*a[$1]/(s-$1)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvifnFiiYKeQpmBjo6Du6u@m/r@6WNs2MdovKNZWxbDW1c@luqAoM69EwdDAQCsxWsUwVl@jWFfFULP2P1A1FxdYMk1BXbU4Jk9dwVDBSMFYwUTBVAGIahQSy7MVdNMU0tBUmQPVGFoqgIAhblWGcIii6j8A)

*-3 bytes thanks to CowsQuack*

Takes the index as the last line of input

Comment: [I saw you mention in chat for more test cases, here's a bash wrapper.](https://tio.run/##S0oszvifnFiiYKeQpmBjo6Du6u@m/r86MdovKNZWxdC6WBtI1rr6uVQXFGXmlSgYGhhoJUarGMbqaxTrqhhq1v4HauDiAkumKairFsfkqSsYKhgpGCuYKJgqAFGNQmJ5toJumkIamipzoBpDSwUQMMStyhAOUVT9BwA "Bash – Try It Online")

Comment: @GammaFunction Thanks!  I had no idea you could write to the file system in TIO.

Comment: @GammaFunction What's the reason we need the space and single quotes around `EOF` there to make it work?

Comment: Single quotes prevent `$expansions` from happening in the heredoc. The space does nothing either way

Comment: `{s+=a[NR]=$1}` shaves 3 bytes

Comment: @Cowsquack thank you. updated.

Answer (score 1):

## Racket, <strike>81</strike> 43 bytes

Accepts a list and index. Outputs rationals (default for division in Racket).
Big thanks to Galen Ivanov for finding the `apply` function. Still learning as I go :) .

```
(λ(l i)(*(/(list-ref l i)(apply + l))100))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYxBDsIwEAPvvMISB7ygihbKlb@sygZFrKoozYG@jT/wpRB6s0ceZ51eVuredX4ib2XHh4U4G0Ll90NHFB55pseldNkCNqIp@YoTXGToe5EqzYtLcl1Be@tUuns7@QcGHDjggitG3ASjtPkP)

Comment: To my understand, `#lang racket` is not counted into bytes if submission is a function.

Comment: I think tsh is right. You can make it work in TIO by assigning the lambda to a variable. Since this is code-golf, you need to remove all the whitespaces [like this](https://tio.run/##HYw7DsIwEER7TjESBbOgCAeSlruY2EYWq4AcF3A27sCVDJtp5qOnKX66x9q26ucbylo2DDHlOSI1fj9UZOEevXM8UvNSuxIT1jU9NKgxHlfhAWbioGJqDHl5qn@D8eWn2l3@nxaYsGOPE84YMAoGg38) for 60 bytes

Comment: `(foldl (λ (a b) (+ a b)) 0 l)` -> `(apply + l)` [for 44 bytes](https://tio.run/##HYxBDoJAEATvvqITD/ZoiKB49S8TmDUbJ2Sz7AHe5h/80ircuiqVzjq8rdSj6/RC3uHA0UKcDKHy@6EjCs@80uNcmmwBu9GUfMUFLtK1rYhUjnFOritoiw6lef4/tsGAEzvccEePh6Df4h8)

Comment: @GalenIvanov The last `)` is matched to `(define` and is not a part of function. So it should not be included too.

Comment: @tsh Yes, of course! I forgot to move it to the footer. So it is [43 bytes](https://tio.run/##HYxBDsIwEAPvvMISB7ygihbKlb@sygZFrKoozYG@jT/wpRB6s0ceZ51eVuredX4ib2XHh4U4G0Ll90NHFB55pseldNkCNqIp@YoTXGToe5EqzYtLcl1Be@tUuns7@QcGHDjggitG3ASjtPkP)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 21 bytes

```perl6
{100*@^a[$^b]/@a.sum}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwv9rQwEDLIS4xWiUuKVbfIVGvuDS39n9afpFCdLShjoKRjoKxjoKJjoJprI5CtDmYZ2gJYgMlsSOQpJEBkGFuBlIL1GtkYAjSCTbB0Cg2VqGaS0GhOLFSIU1BJR4oaArWaAbVHq2irR2ra8hV@x8A)

The simple solution, since I can't use curried parameters with the `$b` parameter being indexed. A funner solution that doesn't have to handle two parameters by using the `rotate` function instead:

```perl6
{100*.[0]/.sum}o&rotate
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYyxDoMwEEP3fIUHxFCuNJeWoKrql0RRxUCmolQBBoT49jSJOla6wWf7@TOGt47ThtrhibizlKfWSHtp53U6fB38MixjfAjnA4xhgiJcCTdCZwmmLx/fs07h/8uhkkn0OncTqyRnsiywsha7AOZhg0P1SmZXQP3DTdU09sziiF8)

But it is unfortunately two bytes longer

Answer (score 1):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 21 bytes

```matlab
@(a,n)a(n)/sum(a)*100
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f/fQSNRJ08zUSNPU7@4NFcjUVPL0MDgf5qCrUJiXrE1F1eaRrShjoKRjoKxjoKJjoJpLBBrgkTNwUKGlkABQ02oMuwIqMIMrMLIAMgzNwPpAhplZGAIMgOu39zQCML@DwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Icon](https://github.com/gtownsend/icon), 53 bytes

```
procedure f(L,i)
s:=0;s+:=!L&\z
return 1e2*L[i]/s
end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0zOz/v/v6AoPzk1pbQoVSFNw0cnU5Or2MrWwLpY28pW0UctpoqrKLWktChPwTDVSMsnOjNWv5grNS8FSVduYmaehiaXAhCUF2WWpGqkaUQb6igY6SgY6yiY6CiYxuqYamqCNQEA)

The only interesting thing here is finding the sum. [Icon](https://github.com/gtownsend/icon) was one of the first languages to have generators. `!` generates all the values of the list `L` that are accumulated to `s`. Normally we need to write `every s+:=!L`, but I used backtracking with `&\z`, which checks if the non-existent `z` variable is `non-null`, which is not, and extracts the next value from the list until exhaustion.

Answer (score 1):

### Batch, 111 bytes

```
@shift
@set s=%*
@call set/as=%s: =+%-%0,s=(%%%0*10000+s/2)/s,h=s%%%%10,t=s/10%%%%10,s/=100
@echo %s%.%t%%h%
```

Takes input as index and list as command-line arguments. Note: Only works for index values from `1` to `9` due to limitations of Batch; a 0-indexed version could be written which would be able to index the first 10 elements. Explanation:

```
@shift
```

Shift the index to `%0` and the list to `%1`...`%9` (or less). Note however that Batch's `shift` does not affect `%*`.

```
@set s=%*
```

Get all of the parameters, space separated.

```
@call set/as=%s: =+%-%0,s=(%%%0*10000+s/2)/s,h=s%%%%10,t=s/10%%%%10,s/=100
```

Change the spaces to `+`s and evaluate arithmetically, thus taking the sum, but subtract the index. Then index into the list, multiply by 10000, add half of the sum, and divide by the sum. Finally perform divmod by 10 twice to generate the decimal places. (The `%` arithmetic operator has special meaning in Batch and normally needs to be doubled but the `call` then requires a further doubling.)

```
@echo %s%.%t%%h%
```

Output the result and the decimal places.

Answer (score 1):

## [Swift](https://developer.apple.com/swift/), 60 bytes

```swift
{(n:[Int],i)->Float in
1e2*Float(n[i])/Float(n.reduce(0,+))}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky7PTCsx@Z@TWqKQpmCr8L9aI88q2jOvJFYnU1PXzi0nP7FEITOPyzDVSAvM0ciLzozV1Iey9YpSU0qTUzUMdLQ1NWvBpuSV5hYrWCmAzQAaGG2oo2Cko2Cso2Cio2Aay8VVUJSZV6KgkaYBVggU1tTk@g8A)

I picked Swift to participate and bumped into its type sensitivity !

Answer (score 1):

## T-SQL 2008, 41 bytes

To find the row number equal to the index:

A division of index and row number multiplied with division of row number and index, if both results are 1, index and row are the same because both are above 0 and integer division round down. This saves 1 byte compared to using IIF

> a - value
>
> b - row number

Using table variable as input. 1-indexed

```sql
SELECT max(b/@*(@/b)*a*100)/sum(a)FROM @x
```

**[Try it online](https://rextester.com/NSX90869)**

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 21 bytes

```julia
f(l,i)=100l[i]/sum(l)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/P00jRydT09bQwCAnOjNWv7g0VyNH879DcUZ@uUKaRrShjoKRjoKxjoKJjoJpLBBr/gcA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
â└╡Æå'W
```

[Run and debug it at staxlang.xyz!](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=83c0b592862757&i=[1.0+2+3+4+5]+4%0A[7.0+3+19]+0%0A[1.0+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1]+5%0A[20.0+176+194+2017+3]+0%0A[712.0]+0&a=1&m=2)

0-indexed. Requires at least one item in the input list to be of the form `N.0` rather than simply `N`. Replacing `/` in the unpacked version with `:_` gets around this restriction at the cost of one byte.

#### Unpacked (8 bytes) and explanation:

```
@AJ*x|+/    Index atop the stack, with the list beneath
@           Element at index...
 AJ*        Times 100
    x|+     Sum of list
       /    Divide
```

Answer (score 1):

## k4, 14 bytes

```
{%+/x%100*x y}
```

can save 1 byte from @Galen Ivanov's solution (in oK) as `%` is inverse operation in k4 as opposed to square root

Answer (score 1):

## [Clojure](https://clojure.org), 40 bytes

```
(fn[a b](* 1e2(/(nth a b)(apply + a))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYwxDsIwFEP3nsLj/zCQH1KinqXKECARoChEVTv09CFiDNibn@1ber@2JVS6h4hYKebZ4@roAAmaTpTXB1rA5EtJO47w3DRUHqgsz7ymDIqYBRpnGIwOhjtmG5HJQfHPqLPD2He0gthL2xtoJe3qz48V/U3rBw)

It's nice to know about the 1e2 trick. :-)

Answer (score 1):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 23 bytes

```
$[a,i][100*a\[i]//∑a]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?JXqAaQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), 39 bytes

```powershell
param($a,$i)$a[$i]/($a-join'+'|iex)*1e2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZHRa8IwEMbf@1fcQ1gbl2KT2YkPhYJsrxtzbyIjqydW1HZJZQ71b@8ubXUKOwLH5X7f9wVSFt9o7BLX6zArDNZskRzqUhu9CZgWLOdMT1k@69MUrop869/7xxz3vCdR1SfPSwMPqASkQRpIAUrAg4CBgJg3LYihDzLm/AobNowcERERMSRCjW4IMvr/kCQmiSTJrUKRkxw@OltKVZF0IV2AilzCQEa3r5Dq/ACpCHAz9zgc4bkwTzpbhi@fK8wqODQipo3RPwJYvp3jnjruS9riHBJgHy1i0O7WFV3csUUn6Ph2f5H0EpBR5DW309fJeGerYtPGzdI2z9Vkl2VoLbiIzjvErz@fC/iOthpriw5sY5vPAl/4F@atNbgya1Yn71T/Ag)

Uses 0 indexed input and doesn't do rounding

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 10 bytes

```
Đ←⦋⇹Ʃᵮ/2ᴇ*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASoA1f9weXT//8SQ4oaQ4qaL4oe5xqnhta4vMuG0hyr//1sxLDIsMyw0LDVdCjM)

Zero-based indexing.
Takes the array, then the index

```
Đ                 implicit input; Đuplicate
 ←                get input
  ⦋               get element at index
   ⇹              swap top two items on stack
    Ʃ             get Ʃum
     ᵮ            cast to ᵮloat
      /           divide
       2ᴇ*        multiply by 100; implicit print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Itr](https://github.com/bsoelch/OneChar.js/blob/main/ItrLang.md), 11 bytes

`#ä#@áS/100*`

zero-indexed, outputs a fraction

[online Interpreter](https://bsoelch.github.io/OneChar.js/?lang=Itr&src=I-QjQOFTLzEwMCo=&in=WzEsMiwzLDQsNV0gNA==)

7 bytes to output the proportion as a fraction:

`#ä#@áS/`

## Explanation

```
#           ; read the first input
 ä          ; duplicate it
  #         ; read the second input
   @        ; get the element at that index in the first input
    á       ; swap the two elements
     S      ; sum up the array
      /     ; divide the element by the sum
       100* ; convert the result to percent
            ; implicit output
```

---

## Itr, [14 bytes](https://bsoelch.github.io/OneChar.js/?lang=Itr&src=I-QjQOFTLzBlMTAwKio=&in=WzEsMiwzLDQsNV0gNA==)

`#ä#@áS/0e100**`

outputs the result as a float

Answer (score 1):

## Rust, 36 bytes

```
|v,i|v[i]*100./v.iter().sum::<f32>()
```

0-indexed, assuming integers cast to floats before the function call

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&code=fn+main%28%29+%7B%0A++++let+solution%3A+fn%28%26%5Bf32%5D%2C+usize%29+-%3E+f32+%3D+%7Cv%2C+i%7C+v%5Bi%5D+*+100.+%2F+v.iter%28%29.sum%3A%3A%3Cf32%3E%28%29%3B%0A++++%2F%2F+%7Cv%2Ci%7Cv%5Bi%5D*100.%2Fv.iter%28%29.sum%3A%3A%3Cf32%3E%28%29%0A%0A++++assert_eq%21%28format%21%28%22%7B%3A.2%7D%22%2C+solution%28%26%5B1.%2C+2.%2C+3.%2C+4.%2C+5.%5D%2C+4%29%29%2C+%2233.33%22%29%3B%0A++++assert_eq%21%28format%21%28%22%7B%3A.2%7D%22%2C+solution%28%26%5B7.%2C+3.%2C+19.%5D%2C+0%29%29%2C+%2224.14%22%29%3B%0A++++assert_eq%21%28format%21%28%22%7B%3A.2%7D%22%2C+solution%28%26%5B1.%2C+1.%2C+1.%2C+1.%2C+1.%2C+1.%2C+1.%2C+1.%2C+1.%5D%2C+5%29%29%2C+%2211.11%22%29%3B%0A++++assert_eq%21%28format%21%28%22%7B%3A.2%7D%22%2C+solution%28%26%5B20.%2C+176.%2C+194.%2C+2017.%2C+3.%5D%2C+0%29%29%2C+%220.83%22%29%3B%0A++++assert_eq%21%28format%21%28%22%7B%3A.2%7D%22%2C+solution%28%26%5B712.%5D%2C+0%29%29%2C+%22100.00%22%29%3B%0A%7D%0A)

Answer (score 0):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
＠；∑÷ＡＡ××
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXVGRjIwJXVGRjFCJXUyMjExJUY3JXVGRjIxJXVGRjIxJUQ3JUQ3,i=JTVCMSUyQyUyMDIlMkMlMjAzJTJDJTIwNCUyQyUyMDUlNUQlMEE1,v=8)

Uses 1-indexing.

The last half just multiplies by 100, so 4 bytes can be saved if percentage over interval [0,1] is allowed as opposed to percentage over interval [0,100].

---

Explanation of example run: list = `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, index = `5`.

```
Stack Visualization                 | Executed Instruction | Explanation
------------------------------------+----------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
..., [1,2,3,4,5], 5, [1,2,3,4,5]    | (program start)      | Canvas starts with the stack populated with the inputs repeating infinitely
..., [1,2,3,4,5], 5                 | ＠, get item         | ＠NA gets the Nth item of A
..., 5, [1,2,3,4,5]                 | ；, swap two ToS     | Swaps the position of the two top items in the stack
..., 5, 15                          | ∑, sum               | Sums all items in an array
..., 0.33333333333333333333         | ÷, divide            | Divides the two top items in the stack
..., 0.33333333333333333333, 10     | Ａ, push 10          | Pushes 10 to the stack
..., 0.33333333333333333333, 10, 10 | Ａ, push 10          | "                    "
..., 0.33333333333333333333, 100    | ×, multiply          | Multiplies the two top items in the stack
..., 33.333333333333333333          | ×, multiply          | "                                       "
...                                 | (end of program)     | Pop and print ToS
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 61 bytes

```forth
: f 8 * over + f@ 0e swap 0 do dup f@ f+ 8 + loop f/ 1e2 f* ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lY9LDsIwDET3OcWsGz6p01AKG64S0RgWSKnSAscP@SBVYsfmWbZm7DH7sNy3N84lxhMYRzTwLxcgwRcoh/ltJyiMHuNzyjOWSSTx8D61e7SOwA3O8RqcXRxsCGkG3oAKdWFXaDKFKZouHeOdWF30tf1JMVSz@d2nQarK@kOtQ01Bqu3XaDWOTi9mf/wA)

It's way too painful to work with arrays in Forth...

A function that takes three items (array length, array start address, index; rightmost being the top) from the main stack, and gives the answer on the FP stack. The array contains floating-point values.

#### How it works

```forth
: f ( len addr idx -- F: ans )
  8 * over + ( len addr addr[idx] ) \ compute the address for the item
  f@ 0e ( len addr F:x F:sum )      \ fetch the float at addr[idx] and push 0 on FP stack
  swap 0 do ( addr F:x F:sum )      \ repeat len times..
    dup f@ f+                       \   fetch the float at addr, add it to the sum
    8 +                             \   increment the addr by one cell
  loop                              \ end loop
  f/ 1e2 f*                         \ compute x / sum * 100
;
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 6 bytes

```
₌i∑/₁*
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLigoxp4oiRL+KCgSoiLCIiLCI0XG5bMSwgMiwgMywgNCwgNV0iXQ==)

Another 6 byter joins the fray. Takes index then list. 0-indexed

### Explained

```
₌i∑/₁*
₌i∑     # Push list[index], sum(list)
   /    # ^ / ^
    ₁*  # times 100
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$ 9 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 7.41 bytes

```
AHz1S/Z2*
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhYrHT2qDIP1o4y0IHyo8IKdhlzRRgY6CobmZkDC0kRHwcjA0FxHwTgWogAA)

Uses 1-indexing. Change `AH` to `AI` for 0-indexing.

##### Explanation

```python
AHz1S/Z2*  # Implicit input
AH         # Index into the list
  z1S      # Sum the list
     /     # Divide
      Z2*  # Multiply by 10**2
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
i$S/ɦ×
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run?header=&code=i%24S%2F%C9%A6%C3%97&footer=&input=%5B1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5%5D%0A4&flags=)

0-indexed. Change `i` to `İ` for 1-indexing.

##### Explanation

```python
i$S/ɦ×  # Implicit input
i       # Index in
 $      # Push the first input again
  S     # Take the sum
   /    # Divide
    ɦ×  # Multiply by 100
        # Implicit output
```